# ajax dont work in firefox

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

sir there is some problem. I work on mac system in codeigniter
this ajax code work on google chrome but dont work on firefox
my firefox properties is Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031218 Firefox/3.0.19

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{ 
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    { 
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        { 
            // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.location.reload(true);

            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/first_project/index.php/admin/selectUser/blank?q=" + str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

please give me solution .
thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error message in console ?

Comment: Firefox 3.0.19? Have you considered updating that to, say, Firefox **16**? :)

Comment: look at here how to use easier ajax in jquery 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: @x3ro some people may have requirements which state they need to support older browsers, there are, for certain reasons, some companies out there which use older browsers such as Firefox 3, IE7 etc.

Comment: @JonTaylor I am aware of people wanting to support old browsers (I myself have been optimizing for antique IE versions quite some time), but does his question reflect such a requirement? Given that (for me) it doesn't, I suggested an updated. Why should I put much more thought into such an effortlessly asked question, especially if I can't really say for sure if he even needs Fx 3.0.19?

Comment: @x3ro  I would say that given the fact he states exactly which version of firefox he is working with then yes this is a requirement.  It may not be a requirement for his system however as far as the question goes firefox 3.0.19 is a requirement.

Answer (score 4):

THIS MAKES NO SENSE

```
        document.location.reload(true);  <-- reload the document

        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  <--set text
```

When you reload the document, there is reason to set the text of the page. The page is exiting. Why are you making an Ajax request if you are reloading the page? Just use a normal form submission if you are going to do that.

Change the function to see what is going on

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status==200) { 
            // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.location.reload(true);
            //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            //console.error(xmlhttp.status + "\t" + xmlhttp.statusText);
            alert(xmlhttp.status + "\t" + xmlhttp.statusText);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: no jQuery therefore your answer sucks :)